# Prove that: $\nu \ll \mu$ iff $|\nu| \ll \mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am aware of this is a VERY simple question. However, may be because the time is almost morning here, I'm stuck somehow.

I want to prove: $\nu \ll \mu \iff |\nu| \ll \mu$.

The definition is simple: if $\nu(E) = 0$ for each $E \in \mathcal{M}$ for which $\mu(E)=0$, then we say $\nu \ll \mu$.

Actually, I am stuck at the forward case $\nu \ll \mu \implies |\nu| \ll \mu$.

Given $\nu \ll \mu$, if we take Jordan decomposition of $\nu$ for some $E$ where $\mu(E) = 0$,$$\nu^+(E) - \nu^-(E) = 0$$hence$$\nu^+(E) = \nu^-(E)$$as far as I see. However, I couldn't see somehow why this both should be equal to zero and hence this implies $|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^- =0.$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hahn decomposition tells you that for measurable $E$, you can find $P \cup N = X$ and $P \cap N = \emptyset$ such that $v^+(E) = v(P \cap E)$, $v^-(E) = -v(N \cap E)$. Apply absolute continuity to $E \cap P$ and $E \cap N$.

Comment: OK then, since $E \cap P \subset E$, $\mu(P \cap E) \leq \mu(E) = 0$ then $\mu(P \cap E) = 0$. Hence, $\nu(P \cap E) = 0$. Similar argument works for $N \cap E$. Since $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ both zero $|\nu|=0$. This is it? (However no positivity assumption given in the exercise for $\mu$, hence I am not sure if we assume monotonicity). (Edit 2: Monotonicity comes from the definition of absolute continuity, hence I guess we are done. Thanks Sanchez!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this via the definition. No need to appeal to the Jordan decomposition. This also has the advantage of working for complex measures too.

$|\nu|(E)$ is defined as $\sup \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left|\nu(E_i)\right|$ where the supremum is taken over all partitions $\{E_i\}$ of $E$. Clearly, if $\mu(E) = 0$, then $\mu(E_i) = 0$ for all $E_i \subset E$ and therefore $\nu(E_i) = 0$. Hence, the supremum is also $0$ and the desired result follows.

Comment: Thanks! But I have never seen this supremum definition of $|\nu|(E)$ before. At least, in Folland's book. But since it is more general, it is more convenient to use this.

Comment: @John The definition is from Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis. Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_in_measure_theory) for more details.