# Show that $\nu\ll\mu $ iff $ \nu^+\ll\mu$ and $\nu^-\ll\mu$

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

I wish to prove that $\nu << \mu $ iff $(\nu^{+}<<\mu \operatorname{and} \nu^{-}<<\mu)$. Where $\nu^{+}$ and $\nu^{-}$ are referring to the positive measures which arise from the Hahn-Jordan decomposition theorem. The reverse implication is trivial but I am struggling to show the forward implication.

Note that I have seen this similar looking question

[Prove that: $\nu \ll \mu$ iff $|\nu| \ll \mu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276713/prove-that-nu-ll-mu-iff-nu-ll-mu)

but the answer uses a definition of $\vert \nu \vert$ which I am not familiar with and have not been taught which suggests to me that the question I have been given should be solvable without resorting to what the person who answered the above question used.

My attempt thus far has been:

$\nu <<\mu$ implies that of $\mu(A)=0$ then $\nu(A)=\nu^{+}(A)-\nu^{-}(A)=0$

Which would imply for all $A$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ we have $\nu^{+}(A)=\nu^{-}(A)$. From this it is not immediate that $\nu^{+}(A)$ and $\nu^{-}(A)$ should be zero. To go further I let $P$ and $N$ be the positive and negative sets  (in the proof of the Hahn-Jordan decomposition theorem) such that $\nu^{+}(A)=\nu(A\cap P)$ and $\nu^{-}(A)=-\nu(A\cap N)$. We then have for all $A$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ that

$$\nu(A\cap P)=-\nu(A\cap N)$$

Although, even doing this, it is still unclear to me as to why $\nu(A\cap P)=-\nu(A\cap N)=0$

Where do I go from here...?

Comment: What definition of absolute continuity for measures are you using? Is $\mu$ a measure or a signed measure?

Comment: $\mu$ is a positive measure. The definition I am using is $\nu<<\mu$ iff $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\nu(A)=0$

Comment: I thought so, I'm glad things are clear now :)

Comment: Please use `\ll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the definition of absolute continuity (for example, the one in Cohn's text), then $\mu$ is a positive measure and the argument goes as follows:

Suppose $\nu <<\mu $ and let $(P,N)$ be a Hahn-Jordan decomposition for $\nu$.

Now, if $\mu(A)=0,$ then $\mu(A\cap P)=0\ $ because $A\cap P\subseteq A,$ 
and so we have $\nu^+(A)=\nu(A\cap P)=0.$  Thus $\nu^+<<\mu.\ $

Similarly, $\nu^-(A)=\nu(A\cap N)=0\Rightarrow \nu^-<<\mu.$ Therefore $|\nu|=\nu^++\nu^-<<\mu.$

Comment: Yes, I just realised $\mu$ was a positive measure. Thank you for clearing that up. Ah, I feel quite the fool.

Comment: I think we've all been there!